# Solve constrained equation with 2 variables

Tags: matlab

EDIT:

I think what I need is to apply fmincon, but I don't know how. I want to do this:

Use fmincon to solve:

Minimize a, subject to the equality constraint

f(q,z) = 0

by varying the unknowns (q,z).

How do I use fmincon to implement this? Thanks!

Here is the entire function:

```
f(q,z) = 60*q^9*z^4 + 120*q^7*z^3 + 80*q^(17/2)*z^3 - 60*q^8*z^3 - 60*q^6*z^3 + 40*q^(15/2)*z^3 + 20*q^(11/2)*z^3 - 20*q^9*z^3 + 175*q^(13/2)*z^2 - 90*q^(15/2)*z^2 + 75*q^5*z^2 - 60*q^6*z^2 - 45*q^(11/2)*z^2 + 40*q^2*z^2 + 30*q^8*z^2 - 30*q^(3/2)*z^2 - 10*q^(17/2)*z^2 + 15*q^(9/2)*z^2 - 20*q^4*z^2 - 10*q^(7/2)*z^2 - 90*q^(11/2)*z + 86*q^(9/2)*z + 75*q^6*z - 45*q^(7/2)*z + 40*q^(3/2)*z - 30*q^7*z - 20*q^(13/2)*z - 24*q^(1/2)*z + 15*q^4*z + 15*q^3*z - 9*q^(5/2)*z - 9*q^5*z + 45*q^4 - 30*q^5 + 30*q^(1/2) - 29*q^3 + 21*q^(5/2) - 10*q^(9/2) - 9*q^2 - 24.
```

----- original post -------

I have a function of 2 variables `q` and `z` like

```
f(q,z) = 60*q^9*z^4 + 120*q^7*z^3 + 80*q^(17/2)*z^3 - 60*q^8*z^3 - 60*q^6*z^3 + ...
```

I need to find

```
f(q,z) = 0
```

with respect to `z`, but this is not possible analytically (resulting in `RootOf`). So instead of finding all points, I want to numerically find the smallest number `z` such that the value pair `(q,z)` fulfills `f(q,z) = 0`. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: From what you've shown... z=0 would work.   But seriously, this is more math than programming.. and that's what MathOverflow.com is for.

Comment: 'with respect to z, but this is not possible analytically' Why is it not possible? With `q=0` any z is possible.

Comment: `fsolve` or if `q` is known, `fzero`? I think @BillJames meant [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) (MathOverflow.net is for "research level math questions").

Comment: Are there only terms with `z` *cubed* after the first term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid *there is no minimum `z`*, as `f(q,z) = 0: q↓0 ⇒ z↓-∞`.

Your original equation can be written as:

[image: f(q,z)]

Writing all the terms following like powers of `z` as `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`, you basically have

[image: f(q,z), with substitutions]

This is a [quartic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) in `z`, which can definitely be [solved analytically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots). Granted, it's a bit awkward, but possible nonetheless.

Note that the fact that `A = f(q)`, `B = g(q)`, `C = h(q)`, `D = k(q)` and `E = m(q)` does not matter, as your goal is to express `z = F(q)`.

Here's one way to find the minimum `z` for which `f(q,z)=0` holds:

```
function find_minimum_z

    solution = fminsearch(@F, 3)

end

function R = F(q)

    R = roots([
        60.*q.^9
        120.*q.^7 + 80.*q.^(17/2) - 60.*q.^8 - 60.*q.^6 + 40.*q.^(15/2) + 20.*q.^(11/2) - 20.*q.^9
        175.*q.^(13/2) - 90.*q.^(15/2) + 75.*q.^5 - 60.*q.^6 - 45.*q.^(11/2) + 40.*q.^2 + 30.*q.^8 - 30.*q.^(3/2) - 10.*q.^(17/2) + 15.*q.^(9/2) - 20.*q.^4 - 10.*q.^(7/2)
        -90.*q.^(11/2) + 86.*q.^(9/2) + 75.*q.^6 - 45.*q.^(7/2) + 40.*q.^(3/2) - 30.*q.^7 - 20.*q.^(13/2) - 24.*q.^(1/2) + 15.*q.^4 + 15.*q.^3 - 9.*q.^(5/2) - 9.*q.^5
        45.*q.^4 - 30.*q.^5 + 30.*q.^(1/2) - 29.*q.^3 + 21.*q.^(5/2) - 10.*q.^(9/2) - 9.*q.^2 - 24
    ]);

    R = min(R(imag(R)==0));
    if isempty(R)
        R = NaN; end

end
```

My trials indicate there is an asymptote at `q=0` for which the minimum, real `z` that solves the quartic tends to -∞.

Indeed this is what you can see when you make a plot of `F(q)`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all terms after the first term have a `z³`, then it's really quite simple:

```
f(q,z) = 60q⁹z⁴ + 120q⁷z³ + 80q¹⁷/²z³ - 60q⁸z³ - 60q⁶z³ + ...
       = z⁴·(60q⁹) + z³·(120q⁷ + 80q¹⁷/² - 60q⁸ - 60q⁶ + ... )

f(q,z) = 0 
⇒  z⁴ · (60q⁹) = -z³ · (120q⁷ + 80q¹⁷/² - 60q⁸ - 60q⁶ + ...) 
⇒  -z · (60q⁹) = 120q⁷ + 80q¹⁷/² - 60q⁸ - 60q⁶ + ...
⇒  z = -(120q⁷ + 80q¹⁷/² - 60q⁸ - 60q⁶ + ...) / 60q⁹
     = -(2q⁷ + 1⅓q¹⁷/² - q⁸ - q⁶ + ...) / q⁹
```

Comment: No, there are not only cubes. Sorry, I just posted the first few lines.

Comment: @user41854: then could you please post the *entire* equation?